# How can I reset an HDMI connection?

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, hdmi

I'm having some difficulties with an external monitor connected via HDMI to a laptop. Among other things, the gamma settings of the monitor get screwed up.  I've found that if I disconnect the HDMI cable, or use the KVM switch, and reconnect, the problems go away.

How can I simulate the disconnection and reconnection of the HDMI cable?

---

I've been trying many things to fix this properly, but can't find a solution. This intel chip and driver just do a poor job in Ubuntu.  The above is another angle I'm trying in order to find a workable solution.

For reference: VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device a7a0 (rev 04)

About the gamma, I know how to use xrandr to adjust this. Indeed I even have a script that watches for DRM events and attempts to fix the display. However, the HDMI state is in a completely broken state and setting the gamma doesn't actually set the right values -- it's like they're being applied on top of previously set values.

Comment: You can't control the power to the HDMI port to simulate a disconnect and reconnect.  Have you tried another cable to make sure that the cable you are using is still good?  HDMI can be very finicky.  I have had several of my cables just go bad on me without ever moving them.  HDMI can cause all sorts of issues with systems when they go bad.  An example is my home satellite receiver would not boot up with the bad HDMI cable in it.  Swapped it out and it has been booting ever since.